# How to specify two if conditions using and in xquery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I m trying the below code :-

```
if($var1=$var2) and if(fn:contains($somevar1, $somestring)
then
(do (this....)
else ()
```

However it doesnt work. Which logical operator can be used between those two ifs?

Answer (score 4):

The second `if` keyword can be omitted:

```
if (
  $var1 = $var2 and fn:contains($somevar1, $somestring)
) then (
  ...
) else (
  ...
)
```